# Cookie is overwriiting issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I have following code I use Jquery cookie plugin to set cookie.I need to store multiple values to a a cookie variable using jquery but every time its overwrite so multiple value doesn't store.please have a look into my code and help me.I have a select box and its name is inserted into a cookie variable every time.

```
$(".cookieul").on("click",function(){


    var a ='';
    var myCookies = [];
    var newValue = $(".client option:selected").text();
    a += newValue;


    myCookies.push(a);

    $.cookie("example", JSON.stringify(myCookies), { expires: 7 });


});
```

Comment: First get stored cookie value, append it and store it again.

Answer (score 0):

You may write like this -

```
$(".cookieul").on("click",function(){

    var newValue = $(".client option:selected").text();// your new selected text

    var old_value_json = $.cookie("example"); // check your plugin get cookie syntax
    var old_value_arr = [];
    old_value_arr = $.parseJSON(old_value_json); //converting your stored JSON string to javascript array

    old_value_arr.push(newValue ); // pushing new value to array

    $.cookie("example", JSON.stringify(old_value_arr ), { expires: 7 });//setting new value to cookie

});
```

Comment: is it fine ?

var myCookies = [];

$(".cookieul").on("click",function(){
     var newValue = $(".client option:selected").text();
     myCookies.push(newValue);

     $.cookie("example", JSON.stringify(myCookies), { expires: 7 });
});

Comment: TypeError: old_value_arr is null

Answer (score 0):

This solves the issue.Any other better way

```
    var myCookies = [];

$(".cookieul").on("click",function(){
     var newValue = $(".client option:selected").text();

     var old_value_json = $.cookie("example");
     myCookies = $.parseJSON(old_value_json)


     myCookies.push(newValue);

     $.cookie("example", JSON.stringify(myCookies), { expires: 7 });


     var storedAry = JSON.parse($.cookie('example'));

     console.log(unique(storedAry));

     function unique(list) {
            var result = [];
            $.each(list, function(i, e) {
                if ($.inArray(e, result) == -1) result.push(e);
            });
            return result;
        }


});
```